# Looping over N lines of a file and storing in multipel lists

Tags: python, list, loops, python-itertools

I have a large file (about 80,000 lines) and I want to store each 10 line block into a separate list. For the first three 10-line blocks I have:

```
N=10 #Number of lines per block

with open("file", "r") as myfile:
        profile1 = list(islice(myfile, 0,N))
        profile2 = list(islice(myfile, 0,N))
        profile3 = list(islice(myfile, 0,N))
```

I expect to have several hundred of these 10-line blocks so this is clearly not a very good way to do this.

How can I incorporate the list generation and `islice` function into a loop?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: make `profile=[]` and just `append` new lists to that

Comment: wouldn't that create just one list called "profile" and result in everything being stored in there?

Comment: yes but then you know index 0 is profile1, 1 is profile2, etc and this would work for varying file lengths

Comment: Thank you that's helpful to know but I will ultimately need them as separate lists.

Comment: `profile` would be a list of lists, what do you need to do exactly?

Comment: The way I have it now I convert each list to an array 
set1=np.genfromtxt(profile1, skip_header=2,usecols=[1,2,3]) and then end up manipulating elements of the arrrays

Comment: Is using `islice()` a requirement?

Comment: not at all it was just the only way I knew how to cut out 10-line chunks

Comment: @GloriaBazargan take a look at my answer below without using `slice()`

Comment: @GloriaBazargan Don't forget to accept it as answer if it is what you want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
chunks = [lines[item:item+10] for item in range(0, len(lines), 10)]  # with Python 2 you can use xrange instead of range for large lists
```

To convert each chunk to array, try the following:

```
import numpy as np

my_arrays = [np.asarray(chunk) for chunk in chunks]
```

Comment: To turn the first chunk into an array I tried: 
set1=np.genfromtxt(chunks[0], skip_header=2,usecols=[1,2,3])
Can I do something similar with a loop to make all the chunks arrays?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
import numpy as np

# read the file in lines
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

# use a list comprehension to split your list in chunks of 10
list_of_lists = [lines[i:i + 10] for i in xrange(0, len(lines), 10)]

# 1st chunks of 10 
print list_of_lists[0]
# 4th chunks of 10
print list_of_lists[3]

# update - turn into arrays
list_of_arrays = []
for i in list_of_lists:
    arr = np.asarray(i)
    list_of_arrays.append(arr)
```

Comment: Is there way to loop over each of the sublists to make each one its own array?